# Change 'modified' time for all files in directory to the 'modified' time of files in other directory using ANT

Tags: ant, last-modified

Higuys.

I have a small problem with `ant touch` task.
What I need to do:

I have directory with sources:

`C:\development\source\project\staticfiles\cartridge\rules\*.drl`

and all files from it are copied to 'target' dir:

`C:\development\target\project\release\rules\*.drl`.

As they are copied using ant, the 'modified' time for newly created files in the 'target' dir is changed respectively, but I need to change to 'modified' time of a corresponding file from the 'source' dir after they are copied. Or in other words, I need 'modified' time of both files to be the same.

I guess `ant touch` can help here, but I do not know how to handle two directories at a time.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use the `preservelastmodified` attribute of the `<copy>` task.

*`preservelastmodified : Give the copied files the same last modified time as the original source files.`*

eg.

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">
    <fileset dir="${src_dir}"/>
</copy>
```